# QThreadPool calls pure virtual function of parent class QRunnable

Tags: c++, qt, pure-virtual

During runtime I get the error message: "pure vitual function called".

QThreadpool seems to call the `pure virtual void run()` of the parent class `QRunnable`, instead off `void run()` in the derived class `Bm`.
Strangely enough the if I ry to call the function manually with `b_1.run();`, there is no problem during runtime.

Here is my class implentation:

```
class Bm : public QRunnable
{ 
    public:
    void run()
    {
        test();
    }
    private:
         void test();
 };
```

Here is my main function where the error happens.

```
int main()
{  
    QThreadPool pool;
    pool.setMaxThreadCount(1);
    BM b_1;

    pool.start(&b_1);

    return 0;
}
```

My Question: Why doesnt Qthreadpool use `Bm::run()` over `QRunnble::run()`?

Comment: Try calling pool.waitForDone() before returning from the main(). Looks like b_1 is deleted before the thread gets started...

Comment: Thanks. This worked. how do i hadle this now? do i delete the question because the answer to my problem seems trivial or should there be a posted answer?

Comment: I think your question is perfectly valid, and may help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread objects gets deleted when going out of the `main()` function scope even before the `QThreadPool` calls `IRunnable::run()`. Using `QThreadPool::waitForDone()` before returning will assure the thread being executed.